# Joomla 2.5: mootools tree in content - how?

Tags: joomla, mootools, joomla2.5

I have an article that has several large lists - and I would like to make them easier to navgiate by converting the -structure into  a mootools-tree (following the example from http://mootree.mindplay.dk/example_1.html ).

So I have disabled any text-filtering (only for my admin user) and am using "no editor" to enable plain-text entry, have entered the following code, hoping it would combine mootools.tree-activation within Joomla and the example - but there's no tree being shown.

Any ideas?

```
    <?php
JHTML::_( 'behavior.tree', 'mytree' );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var tree;

window.onload = function() {

// --- ordinary MooTreeControl example:

tree = new MooTreeControl({
div: 'mytree',
mode: 'files',
grid: true
},{
text: 'Root Node',
open: true
});

tree.disable(); // this stops visual updates while we're building the tree...

var node1 = tree.insert({text:'Subnode 1', id:'1'});
var node2 = tree.insert({text:'Subnode 2', id:'2', icon:'sample_icons.gif#1', openicon:'sample_icons.gif#2'});
var node3 = tree.insert({text:'Subnode 3', id:'3'});

var node2_1 = node2.insert({text:'Subnode 2.1', id:'2.1'});
var node2_2 = node2.insert({text:'Subnode 2.2', id:'2.2', color:'#ff0000'});
var node2_3 = node2.insert({text:'Subnode 2.3', id:'2.3'});

var node2_2_1 = node2_2.insert({text:'Subnode 2.2.1', id:'2.2.1', color:'#00a000'});
var node2_2_1_1 = node2_2_1.insert({text:'Subnode 2.2.1.1', id:'2.2.1.1', color:'#0000ff'});

var node4 = tree.insert({text:'Subnode 4', id:'4', icon:'sample_icons.gif#3'});

tree.expand();

tree.enable(); // this turns visual updates on again.

}

function find_node() {
var node = tree.get( $('nodeid_input').value );
window.alert( node ? 'found: ' + node.text : 'not found...' );
}

</script>


<h2>mooTree 2</h2>
<h4>example 1: basic tree example</h4>

<p>
This demonstrates most of the basic features of MooTree, including enable() and disable() which can be used
to minimize the number of visual updates performed.
</p>

<p>
This example also demonstrates basic usage of the get() method and node id's - for example, type "2.2" in the
text input at the bottom of this page, and press "find node".
</p>

<div id="mytree">
</div>

<p>
<input type="button" value=" expand all " onclick="tree.expand()" />
<input type="button" value=" collapse all " onclick="tree.collapse()" />
<input type="text" value="" id="nodeid_input" value="2.2" /><input type="submit" value="Find node" onclick="find_node()" />
</p>
```

The firebug-Console shows a lot of messages, but I don't see references to my code.

```
[13:59:10.896] GET http://localhost/index.php/2-uncategorised/3-mootree [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1319ms]
[13:59:12.201] GET http://localhost/templates/system/css/system.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
[13:59:12.202] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/css/position.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
[13:59:12.203] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/css/layout.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 5ms]
[13:59:12.203] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/css/print.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 8ms]
[13:59:12.204] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/css/general.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 8ms]
[13:59:12.205] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/css/general_mozilla.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 9ms]
[13:59:12.205] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/css/personal.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 6ms]
[13:59:12.206] GET http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 6ms]
[13:59:12.206] GET http://localhost/media/system/js/core.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 7ms]
[13:59:12.207] GET http://localhost/media/system/js/caption.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 10ms]
[13:59:12.208] GET http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 8ms]
[13:59:12.209] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/javascript/md_stylechanger.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 8ms]
[13:59:12.210] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/javascript/hide.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 9ms]
[13:59:12.183] Unbekannte Eigenschaft '-moz-border-radius'.  Deklaration ignoriert. @ http://localhost/templates/beez_20/css/general_mozilla.css:13
[13:59:12.390] GET http://localhost/media/system/css/system.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
[13:59:12.242] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:123
[13:59:12.246] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:338
[13:59:12.246] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:340
[13:59:12.248] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:382
[13:59:12.255] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property v[i] @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:42
[13:59:12.256] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property Element.prototype.fireEvent @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:260
[13:59:12.256] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property a[1] @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:272
[13:59:12.261] getAttributeNode() sollte nicht mehr verwendet werden. Verwenden Sie stattdessen getAttribute(). @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:343
[13:59:12.268] TypeError: variable a redeclares argument @ http://localhost/media/system/js/core.js:9
[13:59:12.269] TypeError: function checkAll does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/core.js:12
[13:59:12.274] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:247
[13:59:12.275] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:254
[13:59:12.277] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:378
[13:59:12.277] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:385
[13:59:12.282] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:612
[13:59:12.282] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:625
[13:59:12.283] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:628
[13:59:12.283] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:635
[13:59:12.283] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:638
[13:59:12.283] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:650
[13:59:12.284] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:686
[13:59:12.284] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:694
[13:59:12.284] SyntaxError: property name getSelected appears more than once in object literal @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:695
[13:59:12.284] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:699
[13:59:12.284] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:700
[13:59:12.284] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:702
[13:59:12.284] SyntaxError: property name getSelected appears more than once in object literal @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:703
[13:59:12.284] TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:705
[13:59:12.289] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this.Binds @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:27
[13:59:12.291] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this.document @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:192
[13:59:12.291] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this.document @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:170
[13:59:12.293] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this.parsed @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootools-more.js:129
[13:59:12.528] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/images/personal/bg2.png [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 3ms]
[13:59:12.528] GET http://localhost/images/joomla_black.gif [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
[13:59:12.529] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/images/system/arrow.png [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
[13:59:12.530] GET http://localhost/media/system/images/printButton.png [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
[13:59:12.530] GET http://localhost/media/system/images/emailButton.png [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
[13:59:12.531] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/images/personal/personal2.png [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
[13:59:12.531] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/images/nature/karo.gif [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
[13:59:12.532] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/images/content_bg.gif [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
[13:59:12.532] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/images/nature/arrow1.gif [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
[13:59:12.533] GET http://localhost/templates/beez_20/images/personal/tabs_back.png [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
[13:59:12.481] ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable STATE_PROVINCE_VALUE_MAPPING @ resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///C:/Users/MBaas/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/b4ue9vdm.default/extensions/onepassword@agilebits.com.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://onepassword-at-agilebits-dot-com/onepassword/data/src/end.min.js:32
[13:59:12.481] ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable STATE_PROVINCE_REGEX_MAPPING @ resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///C:/Users/MBaas/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/b4ue9vdm.default/extensions/onepassword@agilebits.com.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://onepassword-at-agilebits-dot-com/onepassword/data/src/end.min.js:32
[13:59:12.481] ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable COUNTRY_VALUE_MAPPING @ resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///C:/Users/MBaas/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/b4ue9vdm.default/extensions/onepassword@agilebits.com.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://onepassword-at-agilebits-dot-com/onepassword/data/src/end.min.js:32
[13:59:12.485] ReferenceError: MooTreeControl is not defined @ http://localhost/index.php/2-uncategorised/3-mootree:220
```

The whole thing is running on localhost currently, so I can't provide a Live-URL, sorry.

Comment: What is the version in your Mootools files? In your post you pasted the same code as the example you linked to (also here http://jsfiddle.net/YgqHk/), but you mean you want to make a tree from your html i supose, and not write node per node. If correct please post some code example of your lists.

Comment: The last error on your list is important: `MooTreeControl is not defined` - did you load the MooTree `.js` and `.css` files?

Comment: (1) Weill, as my code did not work, I tried the example - and while I can see it working in plain HTML, it does not work when it is inserted into Joomla-content. In my own case, I am building the tree in the same way (and also have the ul-structure in place, in case JS is not available. When it is, the first thing I do is to hide the div containing the ul...)

Comment: (2) I have not explicitely loaded them, since the `<?php JHTML::_( 'behavior.tree', 'mytree' ); ?>`-stuff is supposed to trigger loading within Joomla. BUT you right, they are actually NOT included! So I have made sure that they are loaded, next error that comes up is `[14:50:58.221] TypeError: variable a redeclares argument @ http://localhost/media/system/js/mootree.js:1`

Comment: Most of the errors you get are warnings that can be ignored. Some are for `/system/js/core.js`, don't know what is there. Anyway you say that it works in plain HTML but not when it is inserted into Joomla-content? I dn't know Joomla that well, what is Joomla content? were do you have the HTML if not in "Joomla content"?

Comment: "Joomla content" is content in the Joomla Content Management System (http://joomla.org ).

Comment: I know Joomla is CMS, what I wonder is: what do you mean it works with plain HTML but nor with Joomla content?

Comment: The alternatives are storing in an HTML-file snd executing that vs. embedding that same content in Joomla-content where finally the tree appears, but all graphical elements (branches, folders) are not shown. I edited the css and changed references to the img, but am still struggling...

Comment: Does your html/script render as is should when you have it in Joomla content? (if you look at the page source)

Comment: The main-problem is that the graphical elements of the tree are not shown, but the items are correctly indented. So I was wondering if perhaps there are "best practices" when using MooTools in content, maybe I need to do something differently or so - but I could not find any examples...

Comment: The graphical elements of the Mootree are `.gif` files. Are they in the right directory? are they rendered in the Mootree elements as `style="background-image:...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved it by using the mooTree-List plugin from http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/typography/… thanks for helping!